# AWS SAM : How to retrieve implicitly created resources information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, boto3, aws-sam

I am using AWS SAM to create infrastructure as code. My current setup (only doing tests for learning) involves among other things this bit of code in the YAML SAM template :

```
API:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Sub ${Env}
      # Authentication on the API will be performed via a Key
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
            CognitoAuthorizer:
              UserPoolArn: !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn
        DefaultAuthorizer : CognitoAuthorizer
        ApiKeyRequired: true 
        # this creates a key, a usage plan and associate them
        UsagePlan:
          CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
          UsagePlanName: !Sub ${Project}-${Env}-UsagePlan
```

The `UsagePlan` part, as specified by the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiusageplan.html) creates an `ApiKey`, a `UsagePlan` and an `ApiUsagePlan` (i.e. an association between the key and the usage plan).

Ok. Now, in a later step, I need to make a call to this API and I therefore the Cognito credentials i.e. my  Cognito username and password (ok, that I get since I create the account myself, like a normal user would do) and I also need the Api Key. Now how am I supposed to retrieve that? First as a developer but also for future normal users?

I can't retrieve it through `Output` in the YAML template. I have tried many things and have read a lot. This is just not possible with SAM.

I can use boto3 to get the UsagePlan id, the ApiKey id and finally the UsagePlanKey. But this seems weird to me because it requires me to go through all existing usage plans and Api keys within the account. And since these ressources are created by SAM... There isn't really a logic I can apply to understand which one I should take. For the UsagePlan I can since I decide its name ... but not for the ApiKey.

So how do I efficiently retrieve the created ressourced id (ApiKey, UsagePlan, UsagePlanKey) by SAM in a "normal" or "state of the art" way ?

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a `AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey` resource to your template, here is an example

```
MyApiKey:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
  Properties:
    Name: SomeApiKey
    Description: Some CloudFormation API Key V1
    Enabled: 'true'
    StageKeys:
      - RestApiId: !Ref API
        StageName: !Sub ${Env}
```

Then `sam build && sam deploy` and you should be able to derive the API Key value in the [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html#aws-resource-apigateway-apikey-return-values)

Perhaps something like:

```
Outputs:
  MyApiKeyValue:
    Description: "the value of Some CloudFormation API Key V1"
    Value: !GetAtt MyApiKey.Value
```

More info on [AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html) here :   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html

Comment: I do like your currect boto approach.  these keys should be a secret and tightly kept

Comment: Indeed, I did it like you proposed in the beginning but it kind of partly defeats the purpose of SAM which is to propose a more straightforward (less lines of code) approach to ressource definition.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it is hard to google, but you do have access to the logical resources created behind the scenes for the API Gateway, including the Usage Plan and its keys.

Given a definition of RestApi like this:

```yaml
Resources
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      # ...
      Auth:
        UsagePlan:
          # ...
```

You can access the ID of the associated Usage Plan Key using a Ref to `RestApi.UsagePlanKey`. You can use this in other resources or in the output as you need:

```yaml
Outputs:
  UsagePlanKeyId:
    Value: !Ref RestApi.UsagePlanKey
```

Note that you will not be able to get the actual value of the Key directly from the template, this is a (likely security related) limitation of CFT (SAM).

However, given the ID, you can access the value via a single API call to API Gateway management API (or using the client libraries).

The Usage Plan Key Id will come in the following format:

```
<api key id>:<usage plan id>
```

You can also get the ApiKey id alone using `!Ref RestApi.ApiKey`

See the following documentation for all available logical ids on Usage Plan:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-api.html#sam-specification-generated-resources-api-usage-plan